# SuiteCRM API set_entry Not Returning New set_entry Result

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm successfully creating a new Account records but am getting `NULL` as the return value. The goal is to map the Accounts record with an email account. I have `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` set to `TRUE` and when I am creating the email address I'm getting a return value with the new record's ID.

```
<?php

$stud_params = array(
    'session' => $this->getSessionId(),
    'module_name' => 'Accounts',
    'name_value_list' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'new_with_id',
            'value' => 1,
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'first_name_c',
            'value' => 'Monica',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'last_name_c',
            'value' => 'Geller',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'aos_products_id_c',
            'value' => '26bec968-365b-c65a-219c-54413aba7769',
        ),
    ),
);

$stud_result = $this->makeRequest('set_entry', self::$URL, $stud_params);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($stud_result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Currently, the result is returning `NULL` even though the record is still being created in the CRM. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After digging into the problem a little bit more this only is happening when trying to create a record in the Accounts module. When I create anything else, the ID is being returned like expected.

Comment: For others who've similar issue: I'd the same problem with the leads module. The problem was I'd '&' character in my data. You should either remove this symbol or url encode it. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 0):

Check if you don't have a logichook aftersave for Account. I have one for manually entry and when i tried to put automatic entry with RESP API it's return NULL.
I have disabled the logichook on my automatic php code (rename php file), and it's work ;-)